# How do I substring a dynamic variable value in windows batch scripting

Tags: batch-file

Not able to substring the dynamic variable inside forloop in Windows batch script.

I have the properties file in my git hub in the below format.
    "collectionName=TestCollectionRun.json=test"

So I have written the below code to fetch this values.But the requirement is that I need to strip of the '.json' part from collection name.With the below code I am not able to set/echo that value.Can you please help on this!

```
@ECHO ON
:BEGIN

IF EXIST "test.properties" ECHO Found properties file, reading file..
SET props=test.properties
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

For /F "delims== tokens=1,2,3" %%G in (%props%) Do (
if "%%I" EQU "test" if "%%G" EQU "collectionName" SET collName=%%H(
SET finalCollName=%collName%:~0,-5
ECHO %finalCollName%
)
)
:END
```

We need the ECHO to return "TestCollectionRun".currently its not returning anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a line content of `collectionName=TestCollectionRun.json=test`, here's a quick rewrite of what I think you're tring to do:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "props=test.properties"
If Not Exist "%props%" (
    Echo Properties file not found!
    Echo Exiting..
    Timeout /T 3 /NoBreak >NUL
    Exit /B
)
Echo Found properties file, reading file..
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1-3 Delims==" %%A In ("%props%") Do (
    If /I "%%C" == "test" If /I "%%A" == "collectionName" Echo %%~nB
)
Pause
```

If you wanted to do something with the collection name within the loop then you would probably need to use delayed expansion:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "props=test.properties"
If Not Exist "%props%" (
    Echo Properties file not found!
    Echo Exiting..
    Timeout /T 3 /NoBreak >NUL
    Exit /B
)
Echo Found properties file, reading file..
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1-3 Delims==" %%A In ("%props%") Do (
    If /I "%%C" == "test" If /I "%%A" == "collectionName" (
        Set "collName=%%B"
        SetLocalEnableDelayedExpansion
        Echo !collName!
        Rem Perform substring task on the variable named collName
        Set "finalCollName=!collName%:~0,-5!"
        Echo !finalCollName!
        EndLocal
    )
)
Pause
```

*Note, these answers will not work, as is, if your string is surrounded by doublequotes, (as in your question body), or if the line content differs (e.g. begins with spaces or tabs).*

**[Edit /]**

Looking at your 'after the fact' question in the comments, it is clear that you do not need to substring the variable at all, so should use the first method posted:

```bat
Echo Found properties file, reading file..
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1-3 Delims==" %%A In ("%props%") Do (
    If /I "%%C" == "test" If /I "%%A" == "collectionName" (
        newman run "%%B" -e "%envName%" --insecure --reporters cli,htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-export "newman\%BUILD_NUMBER%\%%~nB.html" --disable-unicode
    )
)
Pause
```

*This assumes that both `%envName%` and `%BUILD_NUMBER%` have been previously defined correctly.*

Comment: @Diya, it is clear from the solution previously posted under member name `Pav`, that you have registered multiple accounts, please do not do that. Visit [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts), to learn how to have those accounts merged. As for your question, it is technically a new one, _because you've modified the requirements after having received answers_, so should have been posted as a new question. It is clear that you've not understood how to reference a delayed expansion variable, please modify the variable you're referencing delayed using **`!`**'s not **`%`**'s.

Comment: @Diya, I have additionally included another [Edit /] to provide an alternative, as I do not believe that you need to perform any variable expansion with substring replacement, or enable delayed expansion. _If there are further commands being performed within the loop, feel free to follow the advice of my previous comment for your solution instead._

Comment: Works perfect.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
For /F "delims== tokens=1,2,3" %%G in (%props%) Do (
 if "%%I" EQU "test" if "%%G" EQU "collectionName" SET "collName=%%~nH"&echo %%~nH
)
ECHO %CollName%
```

Note the second `)` is now redundant. Your problem has to do with `delayedexpansion` which you are invoking but not using. `call %%collname%%` within  the `for` loop would have shown the value after assignment if required.

This code works by interpreting `%%H` as a filename and assigning simply the name part of `%%H` (%%~nH)

Comment: So in this case cant we substring the value returned by %%H?

Comment: Not directly - the substring syntax is only available on ordinary environment variables. The `~` modifiers as documented in `for /?` are only available for `metavariables` (for-loop control variables) or routine arguments (%0..%9)